# Changing the direction of a Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I change the direction of a [Twitter Bootstrap dropdown](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns)?

I have a dropdown like this:

[image: What I have]

But I want it to look like this:

[image: What I want]

Comment: do you want the actual "**Dropdown v**" to be on the right, but when you open it the arrow of the opened list to be on the left ?

Comment: Simply add one more class `.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-fixed:after, .navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-fixed:before {left: auto; right: 10px;}`. That's it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `pull-right` or `pull-left` classes.

Comment: pull-right will force the entire dropdown to be displayed at the right side of the parent

Comment: @ParvSharma and that's exactly what he wants

Comment: he just wants teh top arrow to be displayed on the other side

Answer (score 29):

From http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment:

> **Deprecated .pull-right alignment**
>   As of v3.1.0, we've deprecated
>   **.pull-right** on dropdown menus. To right-align a menu, use
>   **`.dropdown-menu-right`**. Right-aligned nav components in the navbar use a
>   mixin version of this class to automatically align the menu. To
>   override it, use **`.dropdown-menu-left`**.

In your case, adding `dropdown-menu-right` class to the div that has the `dropdown-menu` class should do the trick.

Answer (score 15):

Here it is (using **dropdown-menu-right**):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
   <li><a href"#">Action</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Bootstrap 4**

use "dropdown-menu-right" and "dropdown-menu-left"

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          @username
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i> Account Settings</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logut</a>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Output:

[image]

for more information visit documentation:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Answer (score 1):

`transform: rotateY` or  `-webkit-transform:rotateY` will do the trick, let's apply it for the dropdown menu;

```
navbar .pull-right > li > .dropdown-menu, .navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu.pull-right {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Or you can insert this into `.dropdown-menu` or `.open > .dropdown-menu` classes due to your exact rquirement. Now it looks like:

[image: drop1]

As can be seen all links need to be reverted so it's simple to do with same CSS rule:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Now it's looking like:

[image: drop2]

Needs a bit cleanup via changing dropdown-menu's position by `left:10px;` and it will look like exactly how you wanted:

[image: final result]

Comment: Holy cow. Very creative, but the library already supports it via 'pull-xxx' classes on the menu itself.

Comment: @Joshua I am informed that library has 'pull-xxx' since I know that there is a library named as Bootstrap. But read carefully op's request and my answer which provides to flip upper arrow of rectangle.

Comment: Your solution is still wacky (but creative!). It would be better to override the CSS of the dropdown, adjusting the position of the arrow itself. The transform creates significantly more CPU load and may also introduce bugs.

Comment: @Joshua manipulating CSS of arrow's itself would be simpler I agree, but I don't think my solution is more wacky than claim to'pull-xxx' solves op's problem :)

Answer (score 1):

***There has been a lot updated, since this post was created, so figured I would give an updated answer.***

For Bootstrap 4+ you can use the classes `dropleft`, `dropright`, or `dropup`; in your `lists/btn-group` parent div.

Now, you can also use buttons as your `dropdown-items`.

Check out *Bootstraps documentation* [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/)

Answer (score -1):

There seem to be no option in Twitter Bootstrap to handle the direction on the dropdown. All that has some effect on the position of the arrow is this class `.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before` Try fiddling with it to view changes in the direction of the drop down